# Play steaming hls in Tizen samsung tv

Tags: tizen, http-live-streaming

I'm developing for tizen Samsung TV and I have not managed to reproduce HLS.

I have installed the SDK Tizen skd Web App, in addition to Samsung Tizen SDK 1.4.

The Samsung operators speak of **webapis.avplay.getAVPlay** method for a player to play this and I need permission **http://developer.samsung.com/privilege/avplay**, but neither the permit nor the method there.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Are you looking for help with code or for documentation?

Comment: The documentation I know where it is.

The problem is that there is no method that Samsung operators say, or the necessary permission http://developer.samsung.com/privilege/avplay.

Comment: Still don't understand. You say that the documentation is incomplete?

Comment: The documentation no. The method and the privilege not is in the API of my sdk.

Answer (score 0):

You can play HLS Stream using the AVplay Player(Sample available on samsungdforum) but it will play videos only on html5 pages and will not play videos on aspx pages.

Comment: Aspx page either use html5 for design of webpage,, why you say it not work in aspx?